# PHP MySQL Query doesn't work, but works from terminal

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here's my code:

```
$gid = (int) stripslashes($_POST['id']);
echo $gid;
```

$db = dbConnect();
$test = $db->query('update games set played = played + 1 where id = "$gid"');
echo $db->error;
echo $db->errno;
die();
}

It works fine from the terminal, and it correctly prints out $gid, and no errors are returned. Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are enclosing the query in single quotes. And in single quotes variable interpolation(also called substitution) does not happen.

Simple example:

```
$who = 'harry potter';
echo 'hi "$who"'; // prints hi "$who"
echo "hi '$who'"; // prints hi 'harry potter'
```

Change your code as:

```
$test = $db->query("update games set played = played + 1 where id = '$gid'");
```

Also from the line: `$gid = (int) stripslashes($_POST['id']);` its clear that `$gid` is an integer and there is not need to enclose it in quotes in your query. So we have:

```
$test = $db->query("update games set played = played + 1 where id = $gid");
```

Comment: `gid` is an INT; no need for quotes at all, but MySQL will implicitly convert a string into an INT if it doesn't fail the conversion.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! My other queries are in single quotes, but they don't have PHP variables in them.

Answer (score 1):

```
$test = $db->query("UPDATE `games` SET `played` = `played` + 1 WHERE `id` = '" . $gid . "'");
```

Answer (score 0):

anything in single quotes is not parsed. do `id="' . $gid . '"`

alternatively wrap the entire thing in double quotes and put single quotes around $gid.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$test = $db->query
("
    UPDATE `games` 
    SET
       `played` = (`played` + 1)
    WHERE `id` ='" . $gid . "'
");
```