# Python sqlite3 query works in terminal, but not from application

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

Have already looked at these similar issues, but have had no joy:

[PHP MySQL Query doesn't work, but works from terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775072/php-mysql-query-doesnt-work-but-works-from-terminal)
[Sqlite update don't working right - python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741251/sqlite-update-dont-working-right-python)

I am using Flask with SQLite and have the following query:

```
g.db.execute( "UPDATE article_views SET views=views+1 WHERE id=:id" , { "id": this_id } )
```

Where this_id is an integer. This executes without error. But when I check my db, the expected update has not occurred.

Does anyone have any insight here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect you need to [*commit* your transaction](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.commit) too:

```
g.db.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks alot, that did the trick. Will accept your answer once it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe the placeholder for Sqlite3 is `?` not `:1` or `%s` style - have you tried to see if the following works:

```
g.db.execute( "UPDATE article_views SET views=views+1 WHERE id=?", (this_id,) )
```

Although I would expect an error of some sort, not just a silent failure...

Comment: Hi, thanks, yes I tried that. Both are valid, I believe. Martjin Pieters gave the correct answer accepted above - i needed to commit my query. I'm used to PDO with mysql, so I thought execute was the end of the line...